# Physical Review Letters Style

Tags: biblatex, columns

Does anyone have latex template like the one they use in Physical Review letters (i.e. two columns in one paper) journal?

Comment: As this is an APS journal, can't you use REVTeX?

Answer (score 19):

There is a package for it, it's called `revtex4-1`, which was designed for all the *APS* and meanwhile also for the *AIP* journals. To use it with *Physical Review Letters* style, consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\title{Some random title}
\author{Me}
\email{mail@example.com}
\author{Myself}
\author{Someone Else}
\affiliation{A University}

\begin{abstract}
Here I tell what I have done... And I have done a lot but it is hard to tell what exactly I have done...
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\blindtext \cite{article-minimal}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1} % Tell bibtex which bibliography style to use
\bibliography{xampl} % Tell bibtex which .bib file to use (this one is some example file in TexLive's file tree)

\end{document}
```

[image]

The important part is the first line of the code, where the options to the `documentclass` specify the following:

- `aps`: The style refers to a journal of the *APS* (Amercian Physical Society) family
- `prl`: The journal shall be *Physical Review Letters* (shortened *PRL*)
- `reprint`: Print the document as it would be printed in the journal. Another option would be `preprint` where the document is set to single column and with larger line spread for proofreading purposes.

Comment: thank you for reply, do you know how I could add citations?

Comment: @user47497 I just edited my code to include also some reference.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. Just one more thing, with your code, my email appears in the last page just before the references, do you know how I can put it in the end of the first paper, and I am actually submitting my paper to Physical Reviews D not Physical Review Letters, does that make a difference to the first line of your code?

Comment: @user47497 If you submit to Phys.Rev.D just replace `PRL` with `PRD`. The placement of the email is defined somewhere in the documentclass' code and I don't have a clue if it can be influenced by just setting some parameter. But anyway the `reprint` option is more or less just for you to see how the finished article will roughly look like. The guys at PRD will quite surely typeset your article on different software which might make it look a bit different. Also where things like the email address should go are defined by them.

Comment: But all the stuff said above should be somewhere in the submission guidelines that you (hopefully) should have read! Above that, if my answer was helpful for you and solved your problem, you can mark it as "accepted answer", which will gain you and me reputation. Have a look at our [tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about that features.

Comment: How to achive the one column bibliographystyle like yours(one column), I always have two column...

Comment: @buzhidao Sorry for answering so late, I was on vacation. Could you post this as a seperate question, together with a MWE to show what you mean. From your description I cannot really deduce what's the issue in your case.

Comment: Version 4-2 is now available.